# How to read column values from xmlstring using forxml clause

Tags: sql, xml, for-xml

In our database table, columns are stored as an xml string, which is shown below.

```
<DocumentElement>
  <PartInfo>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <PartNo>0</PartNo>
    <SerialNo>1</SerialNo>
    <Parameter>0</Parameter>
    <InstalledDate>2013-01-15T00:00:00+05:30</InstalledDate>
    <InstalledTill>2013-01-25T00:00:00+05:30</InstalledTill>
  </PartInfo>
  </DocumentElement>
```

I want to get column values of this string. For example I have to get the value `2013-01-15T00:00:00+05` of `Installed Date` column. How can I obtain this using forxml clause?

Comment: thank u..bt i want to do this in a pgm..not as a stored procedure.Plz tell for that what i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL-Server you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (X XML);
INSERT @T VALUES ('<DocumentElement>
  <PartInfo>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <PartNo>0</PartNo>
    <SerialNo>1</SerialNo>
    <Parameter>0</Parameter>
    <InstalledDate>2013-01-15T00:00:00+05:30</InstalledDate>
    <InstalledTill>2013-01-25T00:00:00+05:30</InstalledTill>
  </PartInfo>
  </DocumentElement>');

SELECT  InstalledDate = X.value('/DocumentElement[1]/PartInfo[1]/InstalledDate[1]', 'DATETIME')
FROM    @T;
```

If you could have multiple `PartInfo` nodes within `DocumentElement` then you'll need to use `CROSS APPLY .. nodes` to get all the `InstalledDate`s

```
SELECT  InstalledDate = PartInfo.value('InstalledDate[1]', 'DATETIME')
FROM    @T
        CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/DocumentElement/PartInfo') p (PartInfo);
```

Comment: Thank u..can u specify what is mean by X.nodes.in my case no declaration can be used.i have to use ina forxml clause within a select query.so what i can use instead of X ?what this variable used for?tell me plz..

Comment: In the example with `CROSS APPLY`, `X` represents your column name.